# EasyMock complaining Not an Interface

Tags: java, easymock

I'm using easymock-3.1.jar, and getting the below exception when I try to mock an object of a class, (not an interface). I don't know what's going wrong. 
Back in the days we needed to use the class extension, but now this is deprecated. 
My code snippet

```
control = EasyMock.createControl();
clientController = control.createMock(MyClass.class);
```

I get the error below:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: com.<my.package>.MyClass is not an interface
at java.lang.reflect.Proxy$ProxyClassFactory.apply(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Proxy$ProxyClassFactory.apply(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.WeakCache$Factory.get(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.WeakCache.get(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Proxy.getProxyClass0(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Proxy.newProxyInstance(Unknown Source)
at org.easymock.internal.JavaProxyFactory.createProxy(JavaProxyFactory.java:24)
at org.easymock.internal.MocksControl.createMock(MocksControl.java:51)
at com.<my package>.<myTest>Test.setUp(myTest.java:36)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50)
at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:24)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:325)
at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:78)
at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:57)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:137)
at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:115)
at org.junit.vintage.engine.execution.RunnerExecutor.execute(RunnerExecutor.java:39)
at java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp$OfRef.accept(Unknown Source)
at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$3$1.accept(Unknown Source)
at java.util.Iterator.forEachRemaining(Unknown Source)
at java.util.Spliterators$IteratorSpliterator.forEachRemaining(Unknown Source)
at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(Unknown Source)
at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(Unknown Source)
at java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp.evaluateSequential(Unknown Source)
at java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp$OfRef.evaluateSequential(Unknown Source)
at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(Unknown Source)
at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.forEach(Unknown Source)
at org.junit.vintage.engine.VintageTestEngine.executeAllChildren(VintageTestEngine.java:79)
at org.junit.vintage.engine.VintageTestEngine.execute(VintageTestEngine.java:70)
at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:229)
at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.lambda$execute$6(DefaultLauncher.java:197)
at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.withInterceptedStreams(DefaultLauncher.java:211)
at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:191)
at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:137)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit5.runner.JUnit5TestReference.run(JUnit5TestReference.java:89)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:41)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:542)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:770)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:464)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:210)
```

Comment: I suggest to ditch easymock and use Mockito instead.

Comment: oh then elsewhere where mockito is used, I get this java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError

Comment: I don't understand your comment in relation to your question or my comment. Please elaborate or edit your question with the additional error when using Mockito. You shuld be using Mockito instead of Easymock, don't mix them.

Comment: your comment is not helpful - thank you for your time.

Comment: I didn't understand your comment I want to have some clarifaction. Easymock will mock interfaces only not classes without an extension. Mockito will do both out-of-the-box and is also activly maintained (Easymock isn't that active anymore afaik).

Answer (score 0):

This shouldn't happen. I highly suspect that there is an old EasyMock version in the classpath. The fact that it occurs on `MocksControl` line 54 tends to prove it.

Comment: I agree - this should not happen.